# how to convert pubkey wif address to hex format with bitcoinjs-lib?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Is there a way with bitcoinjs-lib to import a WIF pubkey:

> 1HVTiWkuGKEJXJupriTdY5MKngcq2bH6P4

and get the hexadecimal version like this:

> 02f632717d78bf73e74aa8461e2e782532abae4eed5110241025afb59ebfd3d2fd

Comment: WIF is Wallet Input Format for a private key, not a pubkey: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format. Also that looks like a P2PKH address

Comment: OK: is it possible to convert P2PKH back to hexadecimal ?

Comment: No, an address is not a public key. It only encodes a hash of a public key, which cannot be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

> WIF pubkey

There is no such thing as a wallet import format pubkey. What you have shared is an address, which is `HASH160(pubkey)`. There is no way to recover the original public key from an address. You could, however, recover the public key from an outgoing transaction from that address, as it would be revealed as part of the unlocking script.